# Process whitespaces from user input

Tags: python, html, css, input

The only reason why I include *Python* in the question is that PHP has the `nl2br` function that inserts `br` tags, a similar function in Python could be useful, but I suspect that this problem can be solved with HTML and CSS.

So, I have a form that receives user`s input in a textarea. I save it to the database, which is Postgres and then when I display it, it doesn't include the line breaks the user supplied to separate paragraphs.

[image]

I tried using the `white-space` CSS property on the paragraph tag:

```
white-space: pre
```

or

```
white-space: pre-wrap
```

But, this is weird, the result was separated lines but the first line aligned in the middle:

[image]

including `text-align:left` didn't solve the problem. I'm sure there is a simple solution to this.

Comment: So the question is how to replace \n characters in a string with blanks?

Comment: I think you are trying to make the textarea of yours a rich text editor. I created an RTE using an iframe which generate the user's content in html and then saves the same html in database.

Comment: @timgeb I guess that is my question. I just wasn't sure if there are specific considerations for this case, and I also wanted to show that I tried `white-space` in CSS. So... how do you do that?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to replace newline characters with `<br />` either before storing it in the database (only once) or when fetching it ([see comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684666/python-html-css-process-whitespaces-from-user-input/24744617#comment-38389540)).

With Python:

```
import re
myUserInput = re.sub('(?:\r\n|\r|\n)', '<br />', myUserInput)
```

With JavaScript (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73J2B/3/)):

```
myUserInput = myUserInput.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

Comment: Quick note: I'd recommend modifying content AFTER you store the original data; style/markup should not be stored in the database since (1) it increases the size of the atoms you're storing and (2) it will be a *pain* to change style in the future.

Comment: @CaseyFalk Good point! I've edited my post highlight your comment.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that storing it will present it to the user in the even that the user must edit the document.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, used your javascript with jquery like this `$('.text').each(function(){ var inner_text = $(this).html();
$(this).html(inner_text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />'));
});` It works, but it adds one or two <br> at the beginning of the text (not sure why), it looks ugly with one-two spaces before each comment. Also tried the Python way and it works correctly, it only needs turning off html escaping: {{text|safe}}, but I am not sure if doing that for every comment and every post is correct and secure.

Comment: @alejoss Are you using Django? Before you upload the user input to the database, you can use `from django.utils import html; myUserInput = html.strip_tags(myUserInput)` - then you'll be sure that it's safe.

Comment: @alejoss Also, you can make the javascript version work, if you additionally add `inner_text = inner_text.replace(/^(?:<br\s\/>)+/g, '');` to remove the (multiple) `<br />` in the beginning of the text.

Comment: Ok thanks! it worked. Yes, I use Django. If anyone finds this useful: I ended up using the Python solution, using `html.strip_tags` in the clean_<fieldname> method in each form and combining it with `{{text|safe}}` in the templates. I hope it is save enough. Cheers.